# wrap a parent div around two divs, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var parentQuestionDiv = $('.ui-droppable').find("[Question='" + parentQuestionId + "']");
var nestedQuestionDiv = $(this).parent();
$(parentQuestionDiv, nestedQuestionDiv).wrapAll("<div id='nestedQuestionGroup' style='border: 1px solid #000'></div>");
```

I want to take the two divs, and place the inside a new parent div. The problem I have is that `parentQuestionDiv` is only wrapped. Not the `nestedQuestionDiv`.

If I change `$(parentQuestionDiv, nestedQuestionDiv`) to `$(nestedQuestionDiv, parentQuestionDiv)`, the `nestedQuestionDiv` is only wrapped.

So why does it not work with both divs? How can I wrap both the divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [second argument in jQuery is for defining the context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context) for searching the element so nothing would happen. To get it work you need to combine them using **[`add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/)** method and then use the **[`wrapAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)** method.

```
parentQuestionDiv.add(nestedQuestionDiv).wrapAll("<div id='nestedQuestionGroup' style='border: 1px solid #000'></div>");
```

Comment: Thank you. But why does this work: $('.one, .two, .three').wrapAll('<div class="wrap">'); ?

Comment: @Bryan :  that's a single string argument (`'.one, .two, .three'`) not multiple arguments....

Comment: Ah, ofc.. So If I did a single string argument, It would work?

Comment: @Bryan :  if you can combine them as a single valid selector then you can..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it in current set:

```
parentQuestionDiv.add(nestedQuestionDiv).wrapAll("<div id='nestedQuestionGroup' style='border: 1px solid #000'></div>");
```